# Normal scrolling when scrolling up, one section per time otherwise with fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I'm using fullpage.js to create some full page sections. Whenever a user scrolls down I want the plugin to scroll down one section at a time (default behaviour).

When a user scrolls up I don't want to slide up only one section at a time, but enable normal scrolling (which can be controlled with *setAutoScrolling = false*, but I can't get this to work.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to achieve this behaviour?

*Edit*: added example code I tried, which doesn't work (obviously, because the setAutoScrolling method gets set when the onLeave event already is triggered)

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({

    onLeave: function( index, nextIndex, direction) {
        var leavingSlide = $(this);


        if(direction == "up") {
            $.fn.fullpage.setAutoScrolling(false);
        }

        if(direction == "down") {
            $.fn.fullpage.setAutoScrolling(true);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing you code it's difficult to resolve you problem.

[here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqyGwx) you can an exemple where it works, you just need to add detection if the user scroll up or down to allow or disallow autoScrolling

I use the method like this :

```
//adding the actions to the buttons
$(document).on('click', '#turnOff', function(){
  $.fn.fullpage.setAutoScrolling(false);
});

$(document).on('click', '#turnOn', function(){
  $.fn.fullpage.setAutoScrolling(true);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added the code I tried without success, which uses the same function you mentioned.

Comment: Maybe try to make us a codepen or fiddlejs ? I will be able to help you more